# Easy conversion from one custom Object to another

Tags: c#

So i have 2 objects/types that are identical to each other in terms of their properties. Right now i am doing to god awful nested loop to convert object 1 into object 2. Is there not a easier way to do this conversion? I thought maybe i could deserialize the one object into the other but wasn't having any luck with this...

Any help in pointing me in the right direction in terms of optimizing how i am doing this would be great... or perhaps there is no getting around the fact that the object has to be rebuilt like this?

```
int acctcount = addFetchAcctList.AddFetchAcct.Length;
AddCreateAcctsReq.AddFetchAcctType[] addFetchAccts = new AddCreateAcctsReq.AddFetchAcctType[acctcount];
for (int i = 0; i < acctcount; i++)
{
    AddCreateAcctsReq.AddFetchAcctType addFetchAcct = new AddCreateAcctsReq.AddFetchAcctType();
    addFetchAcct.FIId = addFetchAcctList.AddFetchAcct[i].FIId;
    addFetchAcct.AcctNumber = addFetchAcctList.AddFetchAcct[i].AcctNumber;


    AddCreateAcctsReq.FIAcctNameType[] fiAcctNames = new AddCreateAcctsReq.FIAcctNameType[1];

    AddCreateAcctsReq.FIAcctNameType fiAcctName = new AddCreateAcctsReq.FIAcctNameType();
    fiAcctName.ParamName = addFetchAcctList.AddFetchAcct[i].FIAcctName[0].ParamName;
    fiAcctName.ParamVal = addFetchAcctList.AddFetchAcct[i].FIAcctName[0].ParamVal;
    fiAcctNames[0] = fiAcctName;
    addFetchAcct.FIAcctName = fiAcctNames;


    int acctbalcount = addFetchAcctList.AddFetchAcct[i].AcctBal.Length;
    AddCreateAcctsReq.AcctBalType[] acctBals = new AddCreateAcctsReq.AcctBalType[acctbalcount];
    for (int j = 0; j < acctbalcount; j++)
    {
        AddCreateAcctsReq.AcctBalType acctBal = new AddCreateAcctsReq.AcctBalType();
        acctBal.BalType = (AddCreateAcctsReq.BalType)addFetchAcctList.AddFetchAcct[i].AcctBal[j].BalType;
        acctBal.CurAmt = new AddCreateAcctsReq.AmountType();
        acctBal.CurAmt.Amt = addFetchAcctList.AddFetchAcct[i].AcctBal[j].CurAmt.Amt;
        acctBal.CurAmt.CurCode = (AddCreateAcctsReq.CurCodeType)addFetchAcctList.AddFetchAcct[i].AcctBal[j].CurAmt.CurCode;

        acctBals[j] = acctBal;
    }
    addFetchAcct.AcctBal = acctBals;

    addFetchAcct.CurCode = (AddCreateAcctsReq.CurCodeType)addFetchAcctList.AddFetchAcct[i].CurCode;

    addFetchAccts[i] = addFetchAcct;
}

header.AddCreateAcctsRq.AddFetchAcctList.AddFetchAcct = addFetchAccts;
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert from one type to the other? And what parts can you modify?

Comment: Why don't you use a single type if they're identical?

Comment: If they are identical to each other in terms of properties, why do you have two unique types?

Comment: http://automapper.org/

Comment: @sous2817 this is a pretty common thing to happen. DTO's to Models usually

Comment: My hands are kind of tied in terms of this. I'm constructing a request to a API and they have provided me XSDs for all requests and responses. I'm getting a response from one of my API calls that i then need to pass in as a request to another API call and these objects, although identical, are of different types...

Answer (score 2):

[Automapper](https://automapper.org/) allows you to map objects by convention or to define your custom rules for the mappings.

After you set up the configuration, your code boils down to

```
addFetchAccts = Mapper.Map<AddCreateAcctsReq.AddFetchAcctType[]>(addFetchAcctList);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code can be simplified using [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx).

Below is an example of using LINQ to create the new objects.

```
header.AddCreateAcctsRq.AddFetchAcctList.AddFetchAcct =
    addFetchAcctList
        .AddFetchAcct
        .Select(acct =>
            new AddCreateAcctsReq.AddFetchAcctType
            {
                FIId = acct.FIId,
                AcctNumber = acct.AcctNumber,
                FIAcctName =
                    acct
                    .FIAcctName
                    .Select(fiAcctName =>
                        new AddCreateAcctsReq.FIAcctNameType
                        {
                            ParamName = fiAcctName.ParamName,
                            ParamVal = fiAcctName.ParamVal
                        })
                    .ToArray(),
                AcctBal =
                    acct
                    .AcctBal
                    .Select(acctBal =>
                        new AddCreateAcctsReq.AcctBalType
                        {
                            BalType = acctBal.BalType,
                            CurAmt =
                                new AddCreateAcctsReq.AmountType
                                {
                                    Amt = acctBal.CurAmt.Amt,
                                    CurCode = acctBal.CurAmt.CurCode
                                }
                        })
                    .ToArray(),
                CurCode = acct.CurCode
            })
        .ToArray();
```

See also:

- [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the properties and assign from one to the other.
Something like:

```
public static void MapValues<Tsource, Tdest>(Tsource source, Tdest destination)
    {
        var props = typeof(Tsource).GetProperties();

        foreach (var sourceProp in props)
        {
            var value = sourceProp.GetValue(source);

            var destinationProperty = typeof(Tdest).GetProperty(sourceProp.Name);
            destinationProperty.SetValue(destination, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what about nested properties?

Answer (score 0):

My version with serialization:

```
// Load object with some sample data
Type1 data = GetData();

// Pass object for conversion object to JSON string
string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);

Type2 data2 = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Type2>(json);
```